Use textobject selection with nnoremap
I hope this is not an XY problem, but I need the following thing: I have parameterized markdown fences (in vimwiki), i.e:
```c
int a = 5;
printf("%d", 5  <++>)
```

So my idea is when I click i.e. <leader>ck the inside of code block gets copied via markdown textobject plugin, and <++> gets replaced verbatim with value of clipboard. Then the result is dumped in my clipboard.
I tried with following:
autocmd filetype vimwiki nnoremap <leader>ck "tyif:let @+ = substitute(@t, "<++>", @+, "g")<CR>

(explanation: first, the inside of markdown fence is copied to register t with "tyif, then the <++> in register is replaced with clipboard, then the result is sent to clipboard)
Alas, the yif doesn't work in remap: I couldn't make the text object work in any way. I tried simpler version of the problem just with selecting the text object like it is shown in github README.md
nnoremap <leader>cv <plug>(textobj-markdown-chunk-i)

but the command gets ignored completely.
Is there any way to do this? Or am I going about it in a wrong way?
Current workaround:
" copies code block and changes "<++>" to the content of the clipboard, and then dumps the result into the clipboard
function! s:GetParametrizedCodeFence()
  let l:tail = search('```$', 'Wc')
  let l:head = search('```\S', 'Wb')
  if !l:head || !l:tail
    echom "No code block found."
    return 0
  endif
  let l:head += 1
  let l:tail -= 1
  execute l:head . ',' . l:tail . 'yank t'
  let @+ = substitute(@t, "<++>", @+, "g")
endfunction

autocmd filetype vimwiki nnoremap <leader>ck :call <SID>GetParametrizedCodeFence()<CR>


The issue you're having with your mapping is likely due to using nnoremap, in specific the "nore" part which disables recursive mapppings.
The if text object from vim-textobj-markdown is a mapping itself, so you need to use a mapping or command that will recognize and execute recursive mappings in order to have it recognized.
Changing your command to nmap might be enough to fix this.
autocmd filetype vimwiki nmap <buffer> <leader>ck "tyif:let @+ = substitute(@t, "<++>", @+, "g")<CR>

(You probably also want to add <buffer> to your mapping, since it's only to be triggered by filetype vimwiki, so it's likely you only want this in vimwiki buffers.)
Most of the rest of your command goes into Ex command-line mode and you only have the "t register and y command in normal mode, so I'd say the likelihood of your mapping breaking due to other existing mappings is slim. You can consider alternatives such as resorting to :normal (without the !) to only execute one part of the command in a way that will expand recursive mappings.
For your second test trying to reproduce the issue with \cv, you have two issues there, the first being the same "nore" issue which makes it not recognize the other mapping (mappings to <Plug> always need to be recursive since those are mappings themselves defined by the original plug-ins) and the other is that you're defining a normal-mode mapping while those are intended for operator-pending mappings, so the correct usage would be using omap, such as the following:
omap <leader>cv <plug>(textobj-markdown-chunk-i)


That's it, thank you very much, great explanation
